# Magnitude of a binary number with circuit

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Given an 8 bit binary number (if negative it is expressed in two's complement representation) design a circuit that allow to obtain the magnitude of that number. (You can use logic gates, adder, multiplexer, demultiplexer, decoder and encoder.)

For sure I have to use full adders, inverters but I don't know how to face the two cases, positive or negative number.

Sorry for my bad English.

Edit:

If I take 9 and -9, 9 is (using 8 bits) 00001001 and in two's complement -9 is 11110111 I know that I can invert every bits of 11110111 and adding 1 to obtain +9 my problem is to distinguish when the number is positive (the output should be the number itself) and if it's negative (the output should be the two's complement of the negative number).

```
   Decimal  Binary 
   -------  --------
         9  00001001
        -9  11110111
```

I can distinguish a positive number from a negative number looking at the left most bit, now how I can put this info into my circuit?

Comment: Hint: by "magnitude" they mean "absolute value". (1) Pick a number between 0 and 127 and write it down in decimal and in binary. (2) Now do the same for its negative value. (3) How would you convert (2) to (1)? [Edit] the information into your question. We'll help you when you get stuck.

Comment: let me take 9 and -9, 9 is (using 5 bits) 01001 and in two's complement -9 is 10111
i know that i can invert every bits of 10111 and adding 1 to obtain +9
my problem is to distinguish when the number is positive ( the output should be the number itself) and if it's negative (the output should be the two's complement of the negative number)

Comment: As I said, [edit] your attempt into the question. Don't bury it in the comments. Hint 2. What distinguishes **all** 2's compliment negative numbers from positive numbers? Also, since your question specifies 8-bit then your 2's compliment must be 8-bit. Use the `{}` code formatting tag to write fixed-width text in your question.

Comment: My bad, i'm new so i'm still learning. thank you for helping me, i hope i edited in a proper way.

Comment: @user1825932 You can avoid adders if you want. In fact, if you k-map out all the output bits vs input bits, you'd find some quite useful XORs. Under ***no*** circumstances do you need a *full* adder!!

Comment: @user1825932 It can be entirely done with (7) ANDs, (6) XORs, (5) ORs, and 1 NOR. Top to bottom. Beautiful symmetry, too. And very easy to compute the worst case propagation time, as well.

Answer (score 0):

A 2's complement number has a 1 in the MSB if it's negative.  Now use your technique in your edit with some XOR gates and an adder with carry in.

Answer (score -1):

- The number (X) is negative if bit 7 is 1.
- If the number is negative you need to output negative X.
- If the number is positive, just output X.
- Selecting between X and -X is done with a multiplexor.
- Negating the number can be accomplished by inverting the bits and adding 1.

I leave it to you to figure out the details.

[image]

Comment: It's a homework question. I was leading the OP through working it out for him/herself.